# std::list - removing elements

Tags: c++, stdlist, outofrangeexception

I am currently using std::list in my application and trying get rid of problem with going out of range.

I really need to use pop_back in one object's method while iterating. I think it may change std::list::end in a some way. Is there any possibility to make it work properly? This code should look simillar to this:

**Edit: I'm using GCC 6.1**

> Edit 2: If you have same problem related to reverse_iterator I recommend you to redesign application as far as it is possible and use casual iterator. It's more intuitive.

```
#include <list>

struct Object;

std::list<Object*> list;

struct Object
{
    Object(bool state) : state(state) {}
    bool state;
    void method()
    {
        if(state) list.pop_back();
    }
};


int main()
{
    list.push_back(new Object(false));
    list.push_back(new Object(true));
    list.push_back(new Object(false));
    for(auto it = list.rbegin(); it != list.rend(); ++it)
    {
        (*it) -> method();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am closing it is lacking MCVE. As obvious from comments beyond answers, the problem is specific to a particular compiler, and the example here is not complete. Need full details.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not so sure. I've linked to another question with a similar problem that claims that iterator invalidation rules are different for reverse iterators.

Comment: Example is complete. It throws exception and it is actually my problem.

Comment: @AkasataAkasata The behavior seems to depend on compiler and version. Please add your compiler, version and compilation flag in the question.

Comment: I've edited post. Compiler is GCC 6.1.

Comment: Can't reproduce with online version of GCC 6.1 on wandbox.

Comment: short answer is that reverse_iterator mimics its underlying iterator - 1. causing deletion of the last element while the reverse iterator is at `back()` to also throw out_of_range

Comment: So what should I do to omit this problem?

Comment: Use a normal iterator instead

Answer (score 0):

This should only be a problem if you are popping back the very last (first with your reverse iterators) element you are visiting right now. This is because you are incrementing the iterator which was invalidated by `pop_back()`

If this is the case, one solution would be to increment iterator first, store the result and than call the `method()`.

Comment: Another approach would be to call `erase`, which will give you a valid iterator or an iterator to the end element. You can then check if the returned iterator is `end()`, otherwise, call method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `it` is invalidated the moment you call `pop_back()` causing undefined behavior when you try to use it. You should store the next step before calling your method:

```
for(auto it = list.rbegin(); it != list.rend();)
{
    auto itr = it++; 
    (*itr) -> method();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why `it` is invalidated. `std::list::pop_back()` only invalidates iterators to the erased element.

Comment: I can't get it too. Erased element is not used in this loop.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are right, the current code shown will only pop back once, on the 2nd element, which would mean `it` already passed it. I overlooked that. Nonetheless, I think OP is not showing accurate code and that the actual code is trying to delete the last element. Current code runs fine as is.

Comment: @RickAstley I get the same problem when I try it myself. It seems related to reverse iterators having different invalidation rules, as using `begin` and `end` doesn't cause the problem,

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What compiler are you using? I get no such problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux can you share MCVE, please? I would like to see it. I do not know of any special invalidation rules for reverse iterators.

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 works fine, Visual Studio 2015 produces the problem. It may be a bug with the VS implementation of reverse iterator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Exactly, MSVC is to blame here.

Comment: It is not actual code. I have shorten it for the question purpose. But it throws exception - so something is wrong.

Comment: I'm using gcc 6.1